# One-liner to load files into java.util.Properties

Tags: java, nashorn

I've many java properties files containing credentials and other configurations, and I'm looking for the most compact code to load these in both Nashorn's javascript and Java.

So far, I'm left with 2 lines:

```
credentials = new java.util.Properties();
credentials.load(new java.io.FileInputStream("credentials.properties"));
```

I've tried this obvious merge but it does not work in Nashorn:

```
credentials = (new java.util.Properties()).load(new java.io.FileInputStream("credentials.properties"));
```

Can these be merged as a one-liner? It does not matter if readability is deeply affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it Java-8 style with a very inconventional use of `Optional` and lambdas, you can try this

```
Properties credentials=Optional.of(new Properties()).map(p->{try{p.load(new FileInputStream("credentials.properties"));}catch(IOException e){}return p;}).get();
```

(Longer, but more readable version with newlines)

```
Properties credentials = Optional.of(new Properties())
    .map(p -> {
             try
             {
                p.load(new FileInputStream("credentials.properties"));
             }
             catch (IOException ex) {}
             return p;
         })
    .get();
```

**Updates:**

without the try/catch it becomes this for java:

```
Properties credentials = Optional.of(new Properties()).map(p -> { p.load(new FileInputStream("credentials.properties")); return p; }).get();
```

and for Nashorn js:

```
var credentials = java.util.Optional.of(new java.util.Properties()).map(function(p) { p.load(new java.io.FileInputStream("credentials.properties")); return p;}).get();
```

Comment: I like this solution. Slightly heavier than expected, but with minor modifications (I've edited your answer) it works for both languages. Thanks!

Comment: How can we close the stream with it? As far as i know propertes.load wont close the stream after loading it. I hope I am not missing something

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work, at least in Java :

```
    (credentials = new java.util.Properties()).load(new java.io.FileInputStream("credentials.properties"));
```

Comment: That's still a two-liner, because you have to keep the variable declaration.

Comment: True, but the declaration was not in the original two-liner either

Comment: I kept the code simple to avoid confusion. In js the original 1st line is "var credentials = new java.util.Properties();". I tried your code and it works, but in js I cannot make it work with "(var credentials = ...". So it might be 1 liner in java but 2 liner in js.

Comment: So that's a 1.5 liner :-)  There may be some js trick to do this (manipulate the prototype ?) but I don't know that much about javascript

Comment: @bwt playing with prototype would make the js and java code diverge too much. The lambdas is most suitable. Thanks for the 1.5 liner. I upvoted it and I'll use it if my vars are predefined in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and safest solution is to introduce a layer of indirection using a utility method:

```
public static Properties loadProperties(File file)
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))
    {
        props.load(fis);
    }
    catch (IOException ioex) { ioex.printStackTrace(); }
    return props;
}

Properties credentials = loadProperties(new File("credentials.properties"));
```

The JS equivalent would be (without the `try/catch`):

```
function loadProperties(file) {
    var props = new java.util.Properties();
    props.load(new java.io.FileInputStream(file));
    return props;
}
```

By adding the `try` statement, you can also catch I/O errors easily.

Comment: Nashorn javascript can use try/catch/finally. I'm really looking for a one liner valid for both js and java. I did not go the function/dry way by choice, otherwise I would have not asked the question

Comment: If neither this nor @bwt's solution works for you, then I'm afraid you're out of luck. There is no way to simultaneously declare a variable *in Java* and call a `void` function on it.

Comment: seems true. I have not explored the lambda way yet.

Comment: I just tried it, and the lambda way is problematic because `load` can throw an `IOException`. Otherwise, this is what it looks like as a Lambda with optional (kinda derpy): `Properties props = Optional.of(new Properties()).map(p -> { p.load(new FileInputStream("credentials.properties")); return p; }).get();`